# How to use CSS Grid to stretch an item to fill a container?

Tags: html, css, forms, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to make a contact form. I want the `<button>` to be at the bottom left of the form. I want the `<textarea>` height to stretch to fill up the remaining height between the `<label>` above it and the `<button>` below it. I'm thinking I could use CSS Grid to properly align everything, but I'm not sure what the best approach would be to make the form responsive.

My code:

```css
.contact-section-container {
    background: #2A6CCF;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 1.042vw, 1.25rem);
    color: white;
    width: clamp(30rem, 41.98vw, 50.375rem);
    height: clamp(30rem, 38.28125vw, 45.9375rem);
    padding: 1.5625rem 3.125rem 1.5625rem 3.125rem;
}

.contact-section-container h2 {
    font-size: 1.875rem;
    color: white;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    margin-bottom: .833em;
}

.contact-section-container div label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}

.contact-section-container div:nth-of-type(n+2) label{
    margin-top: .75em;
}

.contact-section-container div input, textarea {
    background: #F2F2F2;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.contact-section-container button {
    background: #DFE16C;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    width: 10em;
    height: 2.5em;
}

textarea {
    resize:none;
}
```

```html
<form class="contact-section-container">
        <h2>Contact Form</h2>
        <div class="contact-form-input-container">
            <div>
                <label for="contact-page-name-input">Name*</label>
                <input id="contact-page-name-input" type="text"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="contact-page-email-input">Email*</label>
                <input id="contact-page-email-input" type="email"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="contact-page-message-input">Message*</label>
                <textarea id="contact-page-message-input"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Why do you use an input for the message ?, while a **textarea** would be perfect and would allow to really write a message of a few lines.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I edited the question to include a ```<textarea>``` instead. I didn't use it because I actually just found out that it existed haha.

Answer (score 0):

From what I got from your question this is the result you were looking for. You can style the `ID #contact-page-message-input` and give it a `height` to adjust that text box. Then I went ahead and centered your button using a flex display.

I also adjusted your `.contact-section-container` width from `30rem to 32rem` to support these changes. I would suggest not using a `clamp` on your height if you're looking for a fully responsive layout.

```css
.contact-section-container {
    background: #2A6CCF;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 1.042vw, 1.25rem);
    color: white;
    width: clamp(30rem, 41.98vw, 50.375rem);
    height: clamp(32rem, 38.28125vw, 34.9375rem);
    padding: 1.5625rem 3.125rem 1.5625rem 3.125rem;
}

.contact-section-container h2 {
    font-size: 1.875rem;
    color: white;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    margin-bottom: .833em;
}

.contact-section-container div label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}

.contact-section-container div:nth-of-type(n+2) label{
    margin-top: .75em;
}

.contact-section-container div input {
    background: #F2F2F2;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.contact-section-container button {
    background: #DFE16C;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    width: 10em;
    height: 2.5em;
}

/* additions */
#contact-page-message-input {
  height: 200px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .contact-section-container {
    width: auto;
  }
}

textarea {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%; /* 100% of container */
}
```

```html
<form class="contact-section-container">
   <h2>Contact Form</h2>
   <div class="contact-form-input-container">
      <div>
         <label for="contact-page-name-input">Name*</label>
         <input id="contact-page-name-input" type="text"/>
      </div>
      <div>
         <label for="contact-page-email-input">Email*</label>
         <input id="contact-page-email-input" type="email"/>
      </div>
      <div>
         <label for="contact-page-message-input">Message*</label>
         <textarea row="15" id="contact-page-message-input"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That technically works, but I was wanting to avoid using pixels since I want the card width and height to shrink as the screen size gets smaller. I want the button to always be at the bottom left, and the message text input to always fill the space between the message label and the button. I did some more research, and I think ``<textarea>``` would be preferred over a regular ```<input type="text">``` for my message in this case, but I have to look into it further.

Comment: @EthanPartridge please see the adjusted code. Added `textarea` and I made your `textarea width: 100%` to ensure it takes up the full width of the container. Also, added a media query to have the form take up the device width of auto under 600px.  I lowered your container width so that it takes up the full space.

Answer (score 0):

For the message , you should use a textarea instead an input.

For the layout, nowdays the grid-layout is really a powerfull and easy thing to use. the fr unit is really such an handy way to dispatch areas for rows or columns.

Possible example :

```css
.contact-section-container {
  background: #2A6CCF;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 1.042vw, 1.25rem);
  color: white;
  width: clamp(30rem, 41.98vw, 50.375rem);
  height: clamp(30rem, 38.28125vw, 45.9375rem);
  padding: 1.5625rem 3.125rem 1.5625rem 3.125rem;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}
.contact-form-input-container {
display:grid;
grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr 
}
.contact-form-input-container div:last-of-type {
display:grid;
grid-template-rows:auto 1fr;
}
.contact-section-container h2 {
  font-size: 1.875rem;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: .833em;
}

.contact-section-container div label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

.contact-section-container div:nth-of-type(n+2) label {
  margin-top: .75em;
}

.contact-section-container div input,
.contact-section-container div textarea {
  background: #F2F2F2;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.contact-section-container div textarea {
  height: auto;
  resize:none; /* because your layout does not allow it */
}

.contact-section-container button {
  background: #DFE16C;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 10em;
  height: 2.5em;
  margin:1rem auto 0;
}
```

```html
<form class="contact-section-container">
  <h2>Contact Form</h2>
  <div class="contact-form-input-container">
    <div>
      <label for="contact-page-name-input">Name*</label>
      <input id="contact-page-name-input" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="contact-page-email-input">Email*</label>
      <input id="contact-page-email-input" type="email" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="contact-page-message-input">Message*</label>
      <textarea  id="contact-page-message-input"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: this works until the screen gets too small, then ```<textarea>``` exceeds the height of the form, probably due to ```row="15"```. Is there a way to make it grow and shrink more responsively?

Comment: @EthanPartridge You pinned it, remove the row attribute, *(what browser do you use for testing ? i had no worries with chrome & Firefox)* . If that's not enough, then , set `.contact-section-container div textarea {height:0;min-height:100%;}` min-height takes over height ,

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally solved my problem in a responsive way, thanks to everyone that replied to my question. If anyone has any issues or suggestions regarding my answer, please comment.

```css
.contact-section-container {
    background: #2A6CCF;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 1.042vw, 1.25rem);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: clamp(30rem, 41.98vw, 50.375rem);
    height: clamp(30rem, 38.28125vw, 45.9375rem);
    padding: 1.5625rem 3.125rem 1.5625rem 3.125rem;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.875rem;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    margin-bottom: .833em;
}

.text-input-container label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}

.contact-section-container div:nth-of-type(n+2) label{
    margin-top: .75em;
}

.textarea-input-container label {
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}

.text-input-container input {
    background: #F2F2F2;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 2.875rem;
    width: 100%;
}


.textarea-input-container button {
    background: #DFE16C;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    width: 10em;
    height: 2.5em;
    margin-top: .75em;
}

.contact-section-container img {
    margin-right: .75em;
}

textarea {
    flex-grow: 1;
    resize: none;
    background: #F2F2F2;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.textarea-input-container {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<form class="contact-section-container">
        <h2>Contact Form</h2>
        <div class="text-input-container">
            <label for="contact-page-name-input">Name* </label>
            <input id="contact-page-name-input" type="text" name="name"/>
        </div>
        <div class="text-input-container">
            <label for="contact-page-email-input">Email*</label>
            <input id="contact-page-email-input" type="email" name="email"/>
        </div>
        <div class="textarea-input-container">
            <label for="contact-page-message-input">Message*</label>
            <textarea id="contact-page-message-input" name="message"></textarea>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: you asked for grid and end up using flex , that's fine ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus true! Flex was just an elegant solution to my problem